# Sort values from for loop

Tags: php

Hello im trying to sort values (NUMERIC) from for loop, my code:

```
$result_itemid_count = count($result_itemid);
for($x = 0; $x < $result_itemid_count; $x++) {
    echo $result_itemid[$x][0];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

output:

> 172505254931 172505254931 172505254931 172505254931 172505254931
>   172505254931 172295676941 172295676941 172195402570 172195402570
>   172195402570 172295676941 172408848472 172195402570 172195402570
>   172593285746 172593285746 172593285746 172593285746 172263227044
>   172263227044 172195402570 172263227044 172408848472 172408848472

i have no idea how to sort it, i tried sort, usort, ksort
any ideas?

first loop:

```
if ($resp->ack == "Success") {
  $results = '';
  $result_itemid = array();
  // If the response was loaded, parse it and build links
  foreach($resp->searchResult->item as $item) {
    $pic   = $item->galleryURL;
    $link  = $item->viewItemURL;
    $title = $item->title;
    $location = $item->location;
    $itemid = $item->itemId;
    $multiv = $item->isMultiVariationListing;


    if($multiv == "true")
    {
    $result_itemid[] = [$itemid, $title];
    } else {
    // For each SearchResultItem node, build a link and append it to $results
    $results .= "<tr><td align = 'center'><img src=\"$pic\"></td><td><a href=\"$link\">$title - $location</a></td></tr>";
    }


  }
}
// If the response does not indicate 'Success,' print an error
else {
  $results  = "<h3>Oops! The request was not successful. Make sure you are using a valid ";
  $results .= "AppID for the Production environment.</h3>";
}
```

second loop:

```
$result_itemid_count = count($result_itemid);
for($x = 0; $x < $result_itemid_count; $x++) {
    echo $result_itemid[$x][0];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Good luck. Let us know if you run into any _issues_ or even _a question_ at some point. You should also check out: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: really? i just need help

Comment: And I posted some links that will help you improve your question. Since this is a Q&A site (Questions and Answers), there actually need to be a _Question_ before we can give you an _Answer_. I can't see any attempt of sorting in your example. We also have _no idea_ what the original array looks like, what you're trying to sort or what the expected outcome should look like. Sorting can be ascending/descending and since you have a multidimensional array, what key/value should be sorted etc.

Comment: my question is how can i sort the values from the loop. sort by numbers

Comment: You're just outputting the array in a loop. [Have](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) [you](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) [tried](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) a [minimal](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) [research](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php)?

Comment: Magnus is right. You may "just need help", but there isn't enough info here to help you. Try thinking about some of the things he's mentioned, to clarify your exact requirements.

Comment: @AlonEitan yes i did, it dosent work

Comment: _"i tried sort, usort, ksort"_ - Show us that code and we might be able to spot any potential errors. You need to show us what you actually have tried.

Comment: So use [usort](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and compare `$a[0]` and `$b[0]`

Comment: @AlonEitan i did it, dosent work

Comment: @MagnusEriksson check updates

Comment: Where are your sorting attempts? I guess they were between the first and the second loop? As @AlonEitan pointed out, using `usort()` should have done the trick.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i delete it all, non of them works, thats my question how can i do it, i tried put `sort()` and `usort()` between the first and the second.

Comment: it dosent work because Multidimensional Array

Comment: Yes it does, if you do it like @AlonEitan suggested. `$a[0]` and `$b[0]` instead of just `$a` and `$b`. The manual even gives an example using multidimensional array (just compare integers instead of strings in their example).

Answer (score 0):

I hope you expected like below

```
$result_itemid[0][0]=121223;
$result_itemid[1][0]=121883;
$result_itemid[2][0]=121203;
$result_itemid[3][0]=121213;
$result_itemid[4][0]=121235;
$new_array=[];
$result_itemid_count = count($result_itemid);
for($x = 0; $x < $result_itemid_count; $x++) {
 echo $result_itemid[$x][0];
 echo "<br />";
 array_push($new_array, $result_itemid[$x][0]);
}

echo "<hr/>";
sort($new_array);
$result_count = count($new_array);
for($x = 0; $x < $result_count; $x++) {
 echo $new_array[$x];
 echo "<br>";
}
```